# Effect of using unmanaged "dll" on processing time.

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I am using an `unmanaged dll` called  `VTC7200_IO.dll`. 
For obtaining the functions from the `dll` I use below written code (An example)

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool AllocConsole();

    // Intialise IO Library
    [DllImport("VTC7200_IO.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "Library_Initial", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int Library_Initial();
```

The question I have, what happens in terms of `processing time` when your repeatedly import the `dll` file. Can any one give a `conclusive` answer to it, because I am starting a project and was thinking of using `C#` instead of `C++` but would like to know if there will be a big difference in processing time.

Comment: what do you mean by "repeatedly import?"

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it?

Comment: Repeated (from Oxford Dictionary):  Do (something) again or more than once

Comment: Perhaps you should instead ask whether or not the DLL is imported repeatedly. No evidence here that it is. Why do you believe that it is imported repeatedly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is what you are worried about then you shouldn't use P/Invoke with C# and instead write a wrapper with C++/CLI. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky8kkddw.aspx):

> ...C++ Interop uses the fastest possible method of data marshaling, whereas P/Invoke uses the most robust method. This means that C++ Interop (in a fashion typical for C++) provides optimal performance by default, and the programmer is responsible for addressing cases where this behavior is not safe or appropriate.

I can't give an exact number on the performance but just that if you are using a lot of unmanaged calls then wrapping it in a C++/CLI class would be more performant (but less robust out of the box) than just using P/Invoke

Answer (score 3):

Unmanaged assemblies are not "loaded repeatedly." However, they do suffer from type marshaling. You should probably refer to [Microsoft Patterns & Practices, Chapter 7 - Improving Interop Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647812.aspx#scalenetchapt07_topic5) that explains the performance considerations of P/Invoke better (and which is fairly detailed).

From that article:

> The process consists of the following steps shown in Figure 7.1.
>
> 1. The runtime intercepts the call to unmanaged code and identifies the
>      target method in the Export Name Table. If a matching method name is
>      found, the method is invoked. For methods that accept ANSI string
>      parameters, the runtime searches for "methodName" and "methodNameA."
>      For methods that accept Unicode string parameters, it searches for
>      "methodName" and "methodNameW."
> 2. Parameters are marshaled. These parameters can be marked as [in],
>      [out], or ref. Blittable types (such as System.Byte and
>      System.Int32) do not need to be marshaled and are passed directly
>      across to the unmanaged code. Non-blittable types (such as
>      System.Array) are marshaled (converted), based on default marshaling
>      rules and marshaling hints that you can specify by using attributes
>      such as [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)].
> 3. The native code is executed.
> 4. Return values are marshaled back. This includes any parameters
>      marked as ByRef, [out], or [in][out] together with a return value,
>      if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for the link to article: I am going through it.